# Should we (do we?) have a canonical question for remapping key bindings?

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions

I've seen (and answered) quite a few questions on changing key 'A' to do key 'B' or make key 'A' do 'So and so' etc.  I was thinking it might be a good idea to have a general canonical question for remapping key bindings.

If it's a good idea, we should get someone to ask the question. 
Some programs to start with would be `xbindkeys`, `xmodmap` and `xkb`.  I could do `xbindkeys`, but I don't really know much about the others.

What does the community think about this?

Comment: Create a question and see the site's reaction to it? Maybe look for one existing one and improve it? Do we need to keep discussing these over and over again? (Personal feeling here, has nothing to do with moderation or what not...)

Comment: *Do we need to keep discussing these over and over again?*  Have we been?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This answer addresses both Seth's question and Bruno Pereira's comment. And agrees with both. Sort of.*

My guess is that you are asking this because, generally speaking, it's considered bad to post a question that one knows is a duplicate of one or more existing questions. I don't think it's unreasonable to post on meta before making a question with the intention of duping other, pre-existing questions to it.

With that said, though, I think Bruno Pereira is right. When I posted [this question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5856/22949), I was trying to figure out what a canonical partition recovery question *should be like*. Since you already have an idea for what this should be like, I recommend posting it. (Just hold off on duping stuff to it for at least a short while, until we see how people like it.)

Comment: I will hopefully get a question out today.

Answer (score 2):

I have started one here: [How can I change what keys on my keyboard do? (How can I create custom keyboard commands/shortcuts?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-the-function-of-keys-on-my-keyboard)

Please help contribute by editing, answering and voting!