# 2 Q/A about recovery tools and how to recover data

Tags: discussion

There are allot of Q's about the losses of data, and how to recover them.

- [Installed Ubuntu and accidently gave all the hard disk space to Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/113692/36315)
- [HDD recovery tool](https://askubuntu.com/q/298131/36315)
- [Tool for File Recover | Deleted Files Recovery](https://askubuntu.com/q/11298/36315)
- [What are the best Recovery softwares for ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/182867/36315)

<sup>And many more</sup>

My suggestion would be to close them and have only 2 question's:

Q: **What recovery tools exist for (Linux)Ubuntu**???

Per answer a recovery tool with some detailed explanations about the tool itself.

Q: **How to recover my data**?

With per answers covering different scenarios.

Recover data from {`filesystem`} under Ubuntu using {`recovery-tool`}?

Comment: Related: [Do we need a canonical partition recovery question? How shall we make it?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5856/22949)